# audio tag not working in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-audio, wildfly-10

I am trying to stream an audio file in google chrome . The file is hosted at a wildfly server.
Below is the sample code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Audio Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function updateSource(){
            var audio = document.getElementById('wavSource');
            audio.src = 'https://SERVER_URL:8443/FILE_PATH/FILE_NAME.wav';
            var a = document.getElementById('audio');
            a.load();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <audio id="audio" controls="controls">
        <source id="wavSource" src="" type="audio/wav"></source>
        Your browser does not support the audio format.
    </audio>
    <button onclick="updateSource();">Item1</button>
</body>
```

When the button is clicked, the **audio.src** is set to the specified file. This sample code works fine in firefox but does not work in google chrome. If I paste the audio file link in a tab, then also nothing happens (not able to play), But I am able to save the file.

On the server side a softlink is created in **deployment** directory which points to the audio file location.

**Some other things** that I have noticed is that if I am bundling the audio file in an EAR, then I can access it. Now that the audio file is being generated on the fly in a different location , for which I have created a softlink in deployment directory. In this case I am not able to play it.

Can some one please tell me what is that I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: It would better if you post your google chrome version in the question

Comment: my google chrome version is 67.0.3396.87

Comment: Have you checked with other version?

Comment: no, not really.

Comment: Then check with other version also

Comment: If the format is mp3 then what is the behavior of chrome?

Comment: No it is not working with .mp3 file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved the issue. It is related to Wildfly 10.0.0. See [this](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-6413) link.

Answer (score 0):

well you code looks fine. I tried it with different audio files and it works. I think issue must be with your audio file or path.

Comment: That does not answer!

Comment: As mention in the question the audio file works fine in the other brower

Comment: Yes, as I have said the code works fine in firefox (have not tested on other browsers though). I dont understand what is wrong with it. It is fairly straightforward.

Comment: @Rumesh it is 67.0.3396.87

Comment: mine is the same. But it works 100% fine on my browser. check console log for any other errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code works as I checked it with a .wav audio source as you can see below. **Check the actual file on your server, that you want to play, whether it's accessible, playable and it's an actual .wav file.**

If this doesn't work in your Google Chrome, [clear its cache completely](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), update it, restart your computer and check again. It should work then.

Although please, put your script in the bottom of the body tag:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Audio Demo</title>    
</head>
<body>
    <audio id="audio" controls="controls">
        <source id="wavSource" src="" type="audio/wav"></source>
        Your browser does not support the audio format.
    </audio>
    <button onclick="updateSource();">Update Source</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function updateSource(){
            var audio = document.getElementById('wavSource');
            audio.src = 'http://www.wavsource.com/snds_2018-06-03_5106726768923853/people/men/about_time.wav';
            
            var a = document.getElementById('audio');
            a.load();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

*Source: [WavSource.com](http://www.wavsource.com/people/men.htm)*

Comment: But this code is working fine in firefox. So I dont think there is any issue with the file.

Answer (score 0):

All of your audio your files MUST be named as HTTPS, not HTTP. It's a security issue with Chrome.

For one year I couldn't figure out why my random MP3 play JavaScript code stopped working. It worked on Firefox, but not Chrome or Internet Explorer. I tried everything I read online, but nothing worked. I just needed to add an "s" at the end of each "http" for each audio file in the JavaScript code. I had 3,080 files...lol. My webpage works fine now.

Also, your website must be secure. Even if you have security certificates, they won't work unless you activate them, which you can learn how to do online. You can tell if your website is secure by looking for a little closed lock symbol before each web address above.